# Oracle 11g - Scheduled Job Won't Run

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, database-administration

I'm trying to create a job that runs a stored procedure in Oracle. I have tried creating the job with a script, and with the UI in SQL Developer, but haven't had any luck. It shows up in the Scheduler/Jobs folder with no issues, and all the details match the script. I have changed the repeat_interval to something more frequent for testing, but that doesn't change anything. Running the job manually won't work either, though it does show a pop-up saying "Successfully processed SQL command."

I went through the list of configurations mentioned in this answer: [Oracle DBMS Job not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46634593/oracle-dbms-job-not-running), but everything seems correct. The Stored Procedure does run without any issues, it's just the job that's causing me problems.

Here is the script I've been using (repeat_interval's value is the desired outcome, but I've been using different values for it):

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name            =>  'J_CAPTURE_TABLE_DATA_FOR_WEEK',
   job_type            =>  'PLSQL_BLOCK', -- I've also tried 'STORED_PROCEDURE here
   job_action          =>  'CAST.SP_CAPTURE_TABLE_DATA_FOR_WEEK',
   comments            =>  'Capture Table data for older data',
   start_date          =>  SYSDATE,
   end_date            =>  null,
   repeat_interval     =>  'FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MON;BYHOUR=2;',
   enabled             =>  true,
   auto_drop           =>  false,
   number_of_arguments =>  0);
COMMIT;
END;
```

Desired Results: The job actually runs on the schedule (or at all).

Comment: I had the same issue - procedure/job was created/scheduled, but scheduled work wasn't started. As i remember it wasn't privileges issues. I found this article, maybe help: https://community.oracle.com/thread/648581

Comment: Can you show us the code you used to run the job?  Don't use the GUI, use something like `begin dbms_scheduler.run_job('J_CAPTURE_TABLE_DATA_FOR_WEEK'); end; /`.  Then look for the results of that run with this query: `select * from dba_scheduler_job_run_details where job_name = 'J_CAPTURE_TABLE_DATA_FOR_WEEK';`  I suspect the version you have posted has a syntax error - the PL/SQL block is not valid since it doesn't have a `BEGIN` and `END`.  The scheduler has a ton of features and you'll want to be familiar with the data dictionary views so you can troubleshoot them.

Comment: @JonHeller So, I tried using dbms_scheduler.run_job(), and it did execute the job. I probably could have elaborated, but in the code I had a comment about using "STORED_PROCEDURE" in place of "PL/SQL" in the job_type. I tried using BEGIN and END in the job_action parameter, and calling the procedure that way, but still didn't have any luck.

Comment: @Dortimer So the job runs manually, but isn't running as scheduled?

Comment: Correct. Except when you right click the job in Sql Developer and hit run. I tried using the same script to create a job that runs a stored procedure against a different schema, and it worked without issues. From the information I have access to, everything seemed fine, but I'm waiting on a DBA to check their end of things. It'll probably be something dumb on my part.

Answer (score -1):

software: oracle 11g installed locally, intellij idea

Recently, I ran into the similar stuff: created a scheduled job (with interval set) in IDEA, and the command completed successfully. But the job didn't run (it's enabled, the end date is set and everything looks good).

I googled a lot, also looked through [the article mentioned by Tomasz in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932775/oracle-11g-scheduled-job-wont-run#comment96630397_54932775). At last, I just ran the create job thingy from the command line, enable it, it works.

One more thing: querying the `USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS` table, i got the job created in the idea; querying the `DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS` table, i got the job created from the command line.